# RxJava resilent way to combine multiple observables

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have multiple modules that return Observables: `O1, O2, O3... On`
The result of all modules should be combined into one observable `Ocomb` so that individual tasks can fail but the combination is not terminated or influenced by individual issues.
With my current solution I'm encountering various problems as in the following example:

This code combines the output of my modules:

```
public Observable<Data> getModuleData(){
    List<Observable<Data>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    for(MyModule module : modules){
        tasks.add(module.getData());
    }
    return Observable
            .mergeDelayError(Observable.from(tasks))
            .onBackpressureBuffer(MAX_BUFFER)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

Now, I want to display attribute `X` e.g. `'name'` of all emitted data objects:

```
public List<String> getNames() {
    return  getModuleData() 
            .map(new Func1<Data, String>() {
                @Override
                public String call(Data data) {
                    return data.getName();
                }
            })
            .timeout(600, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .toList()
            .toBlocking()
            .firstOrDefault(new ArrayList<String>());
}
```

The `getNames()` method should return a list and therefore block the execution.

**Problem 1**
It seems there is an [issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/issues/50) in RxJava that if I call `observeOn()` and make it blocking it will not return no matter what timeout etc are saying.

**Problem 2**
If `onObserve()` is removed, the code will work but in a different place of the app I'm rendering the results of the non-blocking observable in the UI. Data will be displayed but afterwards my UI does crazy stuff. I have to touch my UI list component to refresh the screen every time data changes.

**Problem 3**
Some of the modules might create internal errors or will not call `onCompleted()`. I thought that a combination of `mergeDelayError()` and `timeout()` could handle these cases and call `onCompleted()` for unresponsive modules. However, if one of the modules does not call `onCompleted()` and the `timeout()` statement is removed the blocking call will never return.

**Questions:**

**What is the best way to combine multiple observable so that individual observables can fail but it's handled as `onCompleted()` / ignored and does not affect the combined observable?**

What is the best solution to make the combined observable blocking and handle the timeout without stopping the execution or ending up in a loop?

Comment: A few questions. Why don't you simply return an Observable<List<String>> for getNames and subscribe to that (in short why are you blocking)? Why are you forcing a timeout?

Comment: I'm refactoring and wanted to keep the interface. The timeout was meant to terminate unresponsive observables.

Comment: If you need to have onNext from all the success observables and you don't care about onCompleted, I think `mergeDelayError()` is the best shot. (there is an issue in combination of mergeDelayError() and observeOn() https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10114). If you need the onCompleted, you can use onErrorReturn, but then also errors will be handled in onNext, onCompleted callbacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the best way to combine multiple observable so that individual observables can fail but it's handled as onCompleted() / ignored and does not affect the combined observable?

```
          Observable.from(modules)
            .flatMap(MyModule::getData)
                .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
                .timeout(600,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Observable.empty())
            .toList()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Above stream could be converted to blocking by adding toBlocking before subscribe(), but does not make much sense beyond testing

Comment: like the flatmap etc approach (had this before i encountered problems with it as well). however, beyond syntactic sugar it's not really adding or changing that much? module combination and consumtion are separated and it seems this would also cause problem 1. the onErrorResumeNext looks like a nice alternative to mergeDelayErrors that i will test now.

Comment: keep in mind that timeout is applied to stream of datas, if you want to apply it to every Observable.getData(), move timeout() inside flatMap function

Comment: thank you! commented before I saw the edit - I think this little change brings it very close to a solution

Comment: have you left out the backpressure statement on purpose?

Comment: The onErrorResumeNext is not an alternative to MergeDelayError. It's simply a way of handling errors.

Comment: no, i just missed it. Usually when coding with rx for mobile i compose my streams such that backpressure exceptions should not be possible, and once i face one, that means code should be fixed upstream

Comment: @JohnWowUs should be read as "alternative to how i handle errors"

Comment: @Philipp are you using 3 args overload timeout(long, Timeunit, Observable) or timeout(long, TimeUnit) ?